# What will be T(n) after second step in a Recurrence Relation

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

T(n) = 2T(n-1) + n

Using back Substitution at first step we get

T(n) = 4 T(n-2) + 2(n-1) +n

If i go further one more step then what i am getting is

T(n) = 16 T(n-4) + 8(n-3) +4(n-2) + 2(n-1) +n

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: The value of T(n) which i got after 2nd step is not correct. I assume i am doing something wrong while substituting but i am unable to figure out where i am going wrong while solving the recurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider a simpler recursion:

$$ T(n) = T(n-1). $$

Using back substitution, we get $T(n) = T(n-2)$, $T(n) = T(n-3)$, $T(n) = T(n-4)$, and so on.

What you do is go first to $T(n) = T(n-2)$, and then substitute this equation into itself to get $T(n) = T(n-4)$. So you're skipping a step.

Answer (score 1):

What you get is correct, but you haven't gone further one more step, but two more steps.

T(n) = 2T(n - 1) + n

First :

T(n - 1) = 2T(n - 2) + (n - 1)

T(n) = 4T(n - 2) + 2(n - 1) + n

Second :

T(n - 2) = 2T(n - 3) + (n - 2)

T(n) = 8T(n - 3) + 4(n - 2) + 2(n - 1) + n

Third :

T(n - 3) = 2T(n - 4) + (n - 3)

T(n) = 16T(n - 4) + 8(n - 3) + 4(n - 2) + 2(n - 1) + n

Comment: Oh so for finding T(n-2) we have to sub it in original Equation...so what i was doing is substituting in equation that i got in 1st step.. Thanks you made it very clear...

Comment: What you did is correct, it's also possible to substitute directly in equation of 1st step, but you won't get T(n - 3). The original equation defines T(n) by T(n - 1), but the other defines T(n) by T(n - 2). With the first, you can get every term that you want. By with the second, you'll only reach terms accessible by substracting 2 to n.

Comment: Ok... So i was directly jumping and skipping some terms in between....i got it ...Thanks for helping.. Thank you Very Much